# ¿Cómo puedo buscar información específica en un archivo csv?

Tags: python, archivo, csv

necesito saber como desplegar una línea de información que esté guardada en un archivo csv. He intentado distintos métodos y no han funcionado. El error que me sale es que los números de la lista están fuera de rango, ya he probado con varios números y verificado que no me esté excediendo del tamaño de la lista.
Este es el pedazo de mi código me da error:

```
if opcion1== 3:
    print("Ingrese su nombre")
    variable=input()
    with open("ejercicio4datos.csv", "r") as file:
        leer_csv=csv.reader(file)
        for row in leer_csv:
            if row[0]==variable:
                print (row)
```

Comment: agrega un ejemplo de cuales son tus datos en el csv

Comment: nombre peso altura fecha horai horaf
     
Paula 130 1.61 23/04/2021 6:00 6:30
Estos son algunos de los datos que tengo en el archivo csv

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no logro visualizar qué problema tienes con tu csv, pero podrías intentar definiendo tu diccionario, ya que vi que tu primera fila tiene las cabeceras

```py
import csv

with open('./ejercicio4datos.csv', 'r') as _filehandler:
    csv_file_reader = csv.DictReader(_filehandler)

    print("Ingrese su nombre")
    variable=input()

    for row in csv_file_reader:
        if row['nombre'] == input
           print(row)
```